# If label contains this and not this prepend *

Tags: javascript, jquery, contains

I am trying to add a * if the label contains city, state, and zip.  Also I only want it to happen if a * does not exist in the label already.  Not sure if you can concatenate contains and not contains together.  Also - I cannot edit the forms and some fields have * randomly put in.  Here are two ways that failed for me.

Here is the Fiddle-https://jsfiddle.net/4o24kyLw/2/

Here is the jQuery

```
//$("label:contains('City'):not(:contains('*'),label:contains('Address'),label:contains('State'),label:contains('Zip')").prepend( "* " );


$("label:contains('City'):not(:contains('*'),label:contains('Address'),label:contains('State'),label:contains('Zip')").prepend( "* " );
```

Got the answer... but maybe I can take this in a different direction... can you simplify the contains. Similar to `label:contains('City', 'State', 'etc...'):not(:contains('*')).prepend( "* " )` or maybe a way that works :]

This is the way it will be if it cannot be simplified - `$("label:contains('City'):not(:contains('*')),label:contains('Mailing Address'):not(:contains('*')),label:contains('State'),label:contains('Postal Code'):not(:contains('*'))").prepend( "* " );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than setting up a complicated query, you could check for the text within the `prepend` function itself:

```
$('label:not(:contains("*"))').prepend(function(_, txt) {
  return 'AddressCityStateZip'.indexOf(txt)>-1 ? '* ' : '';
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2nwe90jm/)

---

The **[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)** function looks for text within a string, and it returns `-1` if not found.

So if `txt` was `'City'`, `'AddressCityStateZip'.indexOf(txt)` would return `7`.

The [**conditional (ternary) operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) returns an asterisk if there's a match – otherwise, it returns nothing.

Comment: i followed that fairly well, but could you provide comments on the function.

Comment: Sure, updated.  Let me know if anything's still unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work, you're just missing a `)`

```
$("label:contains('City'):not(:contains('*')),label:contains('Address'),label:contains('State'),label:contains('Zip')").prepend( "* " );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5686hmnn/

Comment: D'oh - I thought I was on track.  Sometimes it's the second set of eyes that find the simplest mistakes - thanks.

Comment: Heh, it definitely happens. No problem :)

Comment: Maybe I can take this in a different direction... can you simplify the contains.  Similar to `label:contains('City', 'State', 'etc...'):not(:contains('*')).prepend( "* " )` or maybe a way that works :]

Comment: This is the way it will be if it cannot be simplified - `$("label:contains('City'):not(:contains('*')),label:contains('Mailing Address'):not(:contains('*')),label:contains('State'),label:contains('Postal Code'):not(:contains('*'))").prepend( "* " );`

Comment: Gotcha. I figured it was something like that. Rick's answer is best, in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The contains selector is pretty slow, and adding a whole set of them isn't going to help with speed or maintainability. You should use `.filter()` instead:

```
$("label").filter(function(idx){
   var $(this).text() || '';
   return (
             (f.indexOf('City') > -1) ||
             (f.indexOf('Address') > -1) ||
             (f.indexOf('State') > -1) ||
             (f.indexOf('Zip') > -1)
          ) && 
          (f.indexOf('*') !== 0);
}).addClass('required');
```

Also, have you thought about using a css for the call-out instead? It offers several advantages. One of which being you don't really have to worry about modifying the text.

```
label.required:before { content: '* ' }
```

Also, you can style this right from the markup and not need to get javascript involved:

```
<label class="required">..</label>
```

But if you do need to use javascript it is much easier to find these labels:

```
$("label.required")
```

Comment: I cannot edit the forms and some fields have * randomly put in.